# Changing target cell on VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm just trying to figure out if there is a way to change the target cell to run the same code. This code basically opens a directory folder based on the cell *A1* but what I want to happen is add a macro button on the same row that uses the value of the cell on that row. (For example, this my code uses the data on *A1*, I want the code to do that same for *A2* if I put the macro button on row 2)

```
Sub OpenFolder()

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim JobNumber As String
    Dim JobYearLeft As String
    Dim JobYear As String
    Dim FolderNumber As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FirstFolder As String

    JobNumber = Right(Range("A1"), Len(Range("A1")) - 3)
    JobYearLeft = Right(Range("A1"), Len(Range("A1")) - 1)
    JobYear = Left(JobYearLeft, Len(JobYearLeft) - 4)

    i = CInt(JobNumber)

    Select Case i
        Case 0 To 500
        FolderNumber = "0001_0500"
            Case 500 To 1000
            FolderNumber = "0501_1000"
                Case 1000 To 1500
                FolderNumber = "1001_1500"
                    Case 1500 To 2000
                    FolderNumber = "1501_2000"
    End Select


    If (JobYear = 17) Then
        FirstFolder = "M:\2017\" & FolderNumber & "\" '& Range("A1").Value & "*" & "\"
    Else
        MyFolder = "M:\2016\" & FolderNumber & "\" '& Range("A1").Value & "*" & "\"
    End If

    If (JobYear = 17) Then
        MyFolder = "M:\2017\" & FolderNumber & "\" & Range("A1").Value & "*" '& "\"
    Else
        MyFolder = "M:\2016\" & FolderNumber & "\" & Range("A1").Value & "*" '& "\"
    End If

    MyFolder = Replace(MyFolder, " ", "")

    Dim OpenThisFolder As String
    Dim GoToFolder As String

    MyFolder = Dir(MyFolder, vbDirectory)

    GoToFolder = FirstFolder & MyFolder & "\"
    GoToFolder = Replace(GoToFolder, " ", "")
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink GoToFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: By *put the macro button* on the row means manually moving the button with a mouse (or keyboard) to align with the row?

Comment: Actually Im in the process of learning how to turn a into a pseudo button, where in if i double click a specific cell, say cell B2, it runs the OpenFolder macro

Comment: You can actually move the button in the row (or specific cell) you selected and then run the sub routine based on the cell by using `Worksheet Events`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create few `Subs` (one for each button) that would call your `Main Sub` (that's the code that you posted) and pass to it variable containing your cell variable. Like this:

```
Sub ButtonForRow1()
    MainSub "A1"
End Sub

Sub ButtonForRow2()
    MainSub "A2"
End Sub

Sub MainSub(TargetCell as String)
    (...)
    JobNumber = Right(Range(TargetCell), Len(Range(TargetCell)) - 3)
    (...)
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you can try something like this. Here are the things you need?

1. *Form Button* named **Button 1** (or any other name you want just make sure you assign it correctly in below code).
2. Code to position your button every time you select a cell and then assign the action it will execute when clicked. Below code that goes in the *Sheet Module* (Sheet where you process your data) will do just that.

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

       On Error GoTo sureexit
       Dim myButton As Shape, myAction As String

       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Set myButton = Me.Shapes("Button 1") '/* used a form control button */

       If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1:B10")) Is Nothing Then
           '/* target cell is on B1:B10, to get A1:A10 offset by -1 */
           myAction = "'OpenFolder(Evaluate(""" & _
                      Target.Offset(, -1).Address & """))'"
           '/* move the button to the selected cell */
           With myButton
               .Top = Target.Top
               .Height = Target.Height
               .Left = Target.Left
               .Width = Target.Width
               .OnAction = myAction
               .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Follow"
               .Visible = msoCTrue
           End With

       Else
           '/* hide button if selected cell is not between B1:B10 */
           myButton.Visible = msoFalse
       End If

   sureexit:
       Application.EnableEvents = True

   End Sub
   ```
3. Of course you need a procedure in the regular module that you will assign in your *Button 1* on the fly. Below is a simple procedure which expects 1 range argument.

   ```
   Sub OpenFolder(r As Range)

       MsgBox r.Address & ": " & r.Value2

   End Sub
   ```

You can incorporate this with your procedure changing all `Range("A1")` with the variable `r` which is passed every time the button is clicked. Hope this gets you going.